# Issue Performing FullText Search on Entity

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, neo4j

I'm using neo4j as my backend to a Ruby on Rails project and I'm attempting to implement some search functionality. Bellow is my model:

```
class Entity < Neo4j::Rails::Model
    property :name
    has_n(:friends).to(Entity)
    index :name, :type => :fulltext
end
```

I have created records with the following:

```
Neo4j::Transaction.run do
  Entity.destroy_all

  tony = Entity.new :name => "Tony Soprano"
  paulie = Entity.new :name => "Paulie Gualtieri"
  robert = Entity.new :name => "Robert Baccalier"
  silvio = Entity.new :name => "Silvio Dante"

  tony.friends << paulie << robert << silvio
  tony.save
end
```

Lastly my search method looks like this:

```
def search
  terms = params[:q]

  render :json => Entity.all(:name => terms, :type => :fulltext)
end
```

When I run the above search method, I'm getting the following error: `no index on field type`

I've read the [Fulltext Search](http://neo4j.rubyforge.org/guides/rails3.html#fulltext-search) section of the Neo4j-Rails Guides and I don't see what I'm missing to make this work. My understanding is the :name property should be indexed  because of the way I configured the model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which version of neo4j.rb are you using ? If you are using 2.0 you should look at the [Neo4j Github Wiki Pages](https://github.com/andreasronge/neo4j/wiki/Neo4j%3a%3aRails-Lucene).

Here is an example how to solve that using 2.0:

```rb
Entity.all("name: hello*", :type => :fulltext).count
```

I guess this also works in Neo4j.rb 1.3.1.
Hash queries does not work with fulltext search.

The following query:

```rb
Entity.all(:name => "hello*", :type => :fulltext).count
```

will use the exact lucene index and query two fields: `name` and `type`.

Comment: bundle show outputs the following: neo4j (2.0.1), neo4j-community (1.7.1), neo4j-core (2.0.1), neo4j-wrapper (2.0.1)